# how to check if a file is readable by current process using c++ filesystem library

Tags: c++, filesystems

i do not figure out how to properly determine if a file is readable by current process using c++ filesystem library.
i would like to use c++ standard filesystem library for portability.
i thought that it could be possible by bitmasking permissions obtained from file_status
as an example described in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/perms
but i am afraid that it is not for the current running process.

could anybody tell me the proper way?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a file exists and is readable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383617/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-and-is-readable-in-c)

Comment: Not exactly. I prefer a way using c++ filesystem library.